# Single View from Multiple List

Tags: list, list-view

Please find the below print screen. I've two lists List1, List2. Both have few columns.

1) Now I want to create a single view where I can show the records together.

2) Once user will click the column it should open the particular List. For example if user will click on Acme it will open List2 Form. And if user will click PA it will open List1. So once the form will open I can see the all fields with data for the particular list.

First point I can archive using third party web part Bamboo but I'm not sure how to archive the second point. Could you please let me know if you have any solution for this.[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** You can lookup list1 into list2. Thus you can achieve your goal, I hope. 
[image]

**Option 2:** Read items from both list and create a custom view using c# or javascript.

**NB:** Default feature of SharePoint does not support this.